# I have an sql error when i type in a command

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, discord.js

So I'm trying to make dynamic command handling for my bot, but it just doesn't work. Everything works without dynamic command handling.
So this is there error i get when i type in command !work:

```sql
UniqueConstraintError [SequelizeUniqueConstraintError]: Validation error
    at Query.formatError (C:\Users\mmede\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:409:16)
    at Query._handleQueryResponse (C:\Users\mmede\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:72:18)
    at Statement.afterExecute (C:\Users\mmede\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:246:27)
    at Statement.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:129:14) {
  errors: [
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'user_id must be unique',
      type: 'unique violation',
      path: 'user_id',
      value: '485384232131100693',
      origin: 'DB',
      instance: [users],
      validatorKey: 'not_unique',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    }
  ],
  fields: [ 'user_id' ],
  parent: [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.user_id] {
    errno: 19,
    code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT',
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`balance`) VALUES ($1,$2);'
  },
  original: [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.user_id] {
    errno: 19,
    code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT',
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`balance`) VALUES ($1,$2);'
  },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`balance`) VALUES ($1,$2);'
}
```

and this is my work script:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Users, CurrencyShop } = require('../dbObjects');
const currency = new Discord.Collection();




Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'add', {
     //eslint-disable-next-line func-name-matching 
    value: async function add(id, amount) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        if (user) {
            user.balance += Number(amount);
            return user.save();
        } else {
        try {
            const newUser = await Users.create({ user_id: id, balance: amount });
            currency.set(id, newUser);
            return newUser;
            } catch (err) {
                // print the error details
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    },
});



module.exports = {
    name: 'work',
    description: 'balancas',
    execute(message, async) {

        message.channel.send('You hacked someones computer and you gained 1million vbucks')
        currency.add(message.author.id, 1000000);


    }
}
```

If anyone would like to help me I would really appreciate it. I'm new to sql so that would be great if you explained where I made the mistake.

Comment: The error message says you're trying to insert a user_id value that already exists in the table, which is not allowed here - _'user_id must be unique'_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to insert an entry (user) into the users table with a `user_id` that already exists.

Since the users table has a `UNIQUE` constraint, that column is a primary key for the table and there can be *no duplicate* `user_id`s i.e. no two users can have the same user_id.

If you want to edit a particular user, try the `update` command.

Comment: So im getting this now ```AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing where attribute in the options parameter``` when i typed instead of user.create, user.update